# How to use Pug Arrays with Vue?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-component, vuetify.js, pug

I need to switch arrays of pug when the location changes, but I can't figure out how to use that.

Pug Arrays:

```
<template lang="pug">
-
  var activityListRu = [
      {
        i: 'account-switch', 
        t: '1'
      },
      {
        i: 'account-search', 
        t: '2'
      },
      {
        i: 'account-star',
        t: '3'
      }
  ]

-
  var activityListEn = [
      {
        i: 'account-switch', 
        t: '4'
      },
      {
        i: 'account-search', 
        t: '5'
      },
      {
        i: 'account-star',
        t: '6'
      }
  ];
```

Not working:

```
v-row.d-none.d-sm-flex.mb-4
  each card in this.$root.$i18n.locale === "ru" ? activityListRu : activityListEn
    v-col(cols='12', sm='4')
      etc.
```

I wanted to write this using a method, but I also don't know how to correctly point to a pug:

```
v-row.d-none.d-sm-flex.mb-4
  each card in activityListLocale()
    v-col(cols='12', sm='4')
      etc.


  methods: {
    activityListLocale() {
      if (this.$root.$i18n.locale === 'ru') {
        return activityListRu
      } else if (this.$root.$i18n.locale === 'en') {
        return activityListEn
      }
    },
  },
```

Comment: Why are the arrays in the template instead of in the Vue data?

Comment: @Dan, Yes. It is more convenient to make arrays in data, but I would like to know how to proceed in the case as in the example, with Pug

Comment: I don't use Pug, but I think it doesn't make sense to define the data in the template only but expect Vue methods to know what it is.  I could be wrong.